# Bootstrap CSS and JS CDN

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question. How do I use the bootstrap CDN on my site? I'm not sure how to implement it without hosting the files myself.

How do I use link tags to external source files?

Comment: You need to know how to reference external CDN's? Like bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I do. I don't want to host the files myself.

Answer (score 2):

**To utilize Bootstraps css/js files via a CDN, you can use the following:**

Add the following inside your HTML document `<head></head>` tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
```

Comment: Like @Skelly mentioned below, don't forget to reference JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use them from BootstrapCDN like this..

CSS

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS (don't forget to include jquery)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, @Skelly is right. Don't forget to reference JQuery.